# Laravel: Missing Argument error on a POST

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I keep getting the error "Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\Users::deleteMobileAssets()" .  I am making a call from my frontend with Vue.  When I check the headers, it seems correct but I'm not sure what is causing the error.  I've tried wrapping imageType in brackets too: `{imageType: imageType}` but still same error.

```
deleteImage(imageType) {
    axios.post('/delete-mobile-assets', imageType);
}

 public function deleteMobileAssets($imageType)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**POST** data is included in the body of the request that way you are getting Missing argument 1. Try this

```
deleteImage(imageType) {
    axios.post('/delete-mobile-assets', {imageType:imageType});
}

public function deleteMobileAssets(Request $request)
{
  $request->imageType
}
```

Or if you want to implement **DELETE** method. have a look [Delete Method in Axios, Laravel and VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46387850/delete-method-in-axios-laravel-and-vuejs)