# Laravel + Vue The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I am creating an table that displays some data. when i make a delete button , i get an error "The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."

Delete Method on employeelist.vue

```
 deletePost(id)
    { let uri = `api/account/delete/${id}`;
      this.axios.delete(uri).then(response => {
      this.accounts.splice(this.accounts.indexOf(id), 1);
        });
          console.log("Deleted account with id ..." +id);    
        }
```

Route

```
 {
  path: '/admin',
  component: () => import("./components/admin/AdminPage.vue")
  children:[
      {
        name: 'admin',
        path:'',
        component: () => import("./components/admin/Dashboard.vue")
      },
      {
        path:'/admin/employeelist',
        component: () => import("./components/admin/employeeList.vue")
      },
      {
        path:'/admin/calendar',
        component: () => import("./components/admin/Calendar.vue")
      },
      {
        path:'/admin/cloud',
        component: () => import("./components/admin/Cloud.vue")
      },
      {
        path: '/admin/notification',
        component: () => import("./components/admin/Notification.vue")
      }
  ]
},
```

Controller

```
 public function delete($id)
{
    $account = \App\User::find($id);
    if(!empty($account)){
        $account->delete();
        $msg = [
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Account deleted successfully!'
        ];
        return response()->json($msg);
    } else {
        $msg = [
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Account deleted failed!'
        ];
        return response()->json($msg);
    }
}
```

api.php

```
 Route::get('/account','AccountController@index');
 Route::post('/account/store', 'AccountController@store');
 Route::post('/account/search','AccountController@search');
 Route::delete('/account/delete/{id}', 'AccountController@delete');
```

and it get error as i said "The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."

But

when i change the vue route like this

```
{
   path: '/admin',
   component: () => import("./components/admin/AdminPage.vue")
   children:[
  {
    name: 'admin',
    path:'',
    component: () => import("./components/admin/Dashboard.vue")
  },
  {
    path:'/admin/calendar',
    component: () => import("./components/admin/Calendar.vue")
  },
  {
    path:'/admin/cloud',
    component: () => import("./components/admin/Cloud.vue")
  },
  {
    path: '/admin/notification',
    component: () => import("./components/admin/Notification.vue")
  }
 ]
},
 {
   path:'/employeelist',
   component: () => import("./components/admin/employeeList.vue")
},
```

It work succesfully, but i need it on my vue child route. what should i do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46387850/delete-method-in-axios-laravel-and-vuejs

Comment: thank you for your link reference but i already tried all solution there and somehow it still not worked yet and still give me 405 method