# Put and Delete Request with Axios XMLHttpRequest shows error 419

Tags: ajax, laravel, axios

I am new to Axios when using Axios to get data from laravel 8 using react js. It was working fine and I could do crud operation but now it shows an error in the console as  `DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/delete-std/202 419 (unknown status)` as well as `PUT http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/update-std/202 419 (unknown status)`. The same error was shown for `post` also and it was rectified by adding

```
protected $except = [        
        'api/add-std',        
    ];
```

in the VerifyCsrfToken.php file

It's the calling JS code:

```
 delete_confirm  = async () => { 
        const res = await axios.delete(`http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/delete-std/${this.state.idProcesing}`);       
        if(res.data.status === 200)
        {            
            this.setState({
                showModal:false,                  
                idProcesing: '',                
            });
             
        }
        
      }
```

Handling Laravel Route code:

```
Route::delete('delete-std/{id}', [StudentDashboard::class, 'delete']);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you including the CSRF token into the axios request or not?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have not added but it was working fine and the next day it starts showing the error. its the delete request from react to laravel `const res = await axios.delete(`http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/delete-std/${this.state.idProcesing}`);`. Data is getting with no errors and inserted with no errors.

Comment: Can you try adding `_method` with a value of `delete` to the request? I know it won't be necessary with Axios but give it a try.

Comment: like this axios.delete(`http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/delete-std/_method(${this.state.idProcesing})`); ? it's the same error with this.

Comment: not like that. it should be included in the body of the request. `{"_method":"delete",...}`

Comment: I don't get this. can u pls type that completely?

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46387850/delete-method-in-axios-laravel-and-vuejs and see if you can understand how to add `_method`

Comment: I tried that one and it shows the same error.

Comment: Can't you add the calling js code and the handling Laravel routes code to the question?

Comment: js and laravel code added to the question. pls, check it.

Comment: See mostly 419 errors occurs with methods expect to GET because of missing X-CSRF header. Refer: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token and also https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-can-i-use-csrf-token-with-axios-post-method

Comment: OK thanks. Let me try.